# Setting the Database in MongdoDB-data-REST-complete

Tags: spring, spring-rest, spring-mongodb

I am using the Spring Guide for the MongoDB-data-rest-complete example and I want it to use a specific mongodb database, rather than the default one ('test'). How do I do this?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Just add a MongoDB URI like `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test` to `application.properties`

Comment: What directory do I create an application.properties file in? The same as my pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it running! The answer is that the application.properties file may go in the src/main/resources folder!